# Passing 2D array into function and filling it with numbers

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, visual-c++

I'm trying to do task in C++. I need create this function:

```
void fillArray(std::array<std::array<int, maxColumns>, maxRows> array, size_t rows, size_t columns) {

}
```

Right now my example code looks like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
constexpr int maxColumns = 42;
constexpr int maxRows = 334;

void fillArray(std::array<std::array<int, maxColumns>, maxRows> array, size_t rows, size_t columns) {

}


int main()
{
    
}
```

I need to fill the array with numbers from 1 to rows*columns starting from [0][0] and diagonally. How to declare and initialize the function with array in this example and then fill it diagonally? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What errors do you get? Please copy and paste them into your question.

Comment: read about pass by reference (vs pass by value). If you need help with code, please include a [mcve] and the compiler error message in the quesiton

Comment: [Add required things](https://wandbox.org/permlink/jNJg8qDzqrSSQvIx).

Comment: Ok I changed the question a little bit.

Comment: You probably forgot to: `#include <array>` or at least the code in the question does not do that.

Comment: @drescherjm yeah you're right I forgot about It.

Comment: Is the error not fixed after you add `#include <array>`?

Comment: @Yksisarvinen Yeah the error is fixed, but now the second part of the question is how to fill the array diagonally in this example.

Answer (score 2):

It should be

```
template <std::size_t maxColumns, std::size_t maxRows>
void fillArray(std::array<std::array<int, maxColumns>, maxRows>& array) {
// ...
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3c72a61f356bcdfd)

Comment: Unless OP wants a 100x100 array and only fill 10x10 from that.

Comment: But how do I pass the array into this function ? I just do simply fillArray(array) or do I need to declare it somehow else ?

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose you use a simple one-dimensional valarray (or array if you insist) of the size *width * height* wrapped in a class:

```
class Matrix
{
private:
    std::valarray<int> _data;
    int _width, _height;

public:
    Matrix(int width, int height) : _width(width), _height(height), _data(width * height)
    {
    }
}
```

Then you can add a member function that maps x, y coordinates to an item reference:

```
int& item(int x, int y) { return _data[x + _width * y]; }
```

... and another one for filling it diagonally like this:

```
void fillDiagonally(int value = 0, int step = 1)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < _height + _width; ++i) {
        // calculate starting coordinates (along left edge and then bottom edge)
        int row = i < _height ? i : _height - 1;
        int col = i < _height ? 0 : i - _height + 1;
        // move diagonally up and right until you reach margins, while filling-in values
        for (int j = 0; j < _width - col && j <= row; ++j) {
            item(col + j, row - j) = value;
            value += step;
        }
    }
}
```

and use it like this:

```
int main()
{
    Matrix m(8, 5);
    m.fillDiagonally(1);
}
```

This way, you don't need to pass the array as an argument, because it's a part of the class. Otherwise you would have to pass it by reference, like you were suggested above.